Would switching out NPC class levels for PC class levels change the CR of a monster?
As NPC classes are designed for NPC’s, I’d think that it would, but I’d like to get some clarification. If the CR does change, by how much?

I don’t know the answer off the top of my head—it definitely should but I’m not sure if the rules actually cover it, much less assign a number—but you may also want to know that, ultimately, Pathfinder’s CR system is just not that reliable. Even if there’s an official answer here, it probably won’t actually be right for the specific character: for instance, swapping expert for wizard is a large upgrade, but swapping adept for fighter might actually be a downgrade. At the end of the day, Pathfinder just isn’t balanced well enough for CR to work as written.

Per the Bestiary appendix on monster advancement (here), how much a level added to a monster changes its CR depends on whether that class is considered 'Key', or generally if the class being added has synergy with the monster being modified. Key classes add one to the CR for every level and non-Key classes add a point to CR for every two levels. Partially because the attached table is missing quite a few classes, I generally assume that I'm making a synergistic build regardless and treat the resulting CR as if it was from a Key class. NPC classes are noted to never be considered Key, while low-synergy PC classes can eventually become Key if there are enough levels to overshadow the original monster stats.

Table 2–4 gives general guidelines regarding which core classes add directly to a monster’s abilities based on its role. Classes that are marked “key” generally add 1 to a creature’s CR for each level added. Classes marked with a “—” increase a creature’s CR by 1 for every 2 class levels added until the number of levels added are equal to (or exceed) the creature’s original CR, at which point they are treated as “key” levels (adding 1 to the creature’s CR for each level added). Creatures that fall into multiple roles treat a class as key if either of its roles treat the class as key. Note that levels in NPC classes are never considered key.

So, assuming that the PC class being swapped in is useful for the monster in question, RAW the CR should increase by half the number of levels being swapped (going from counting for 1/2 levels to all of them). Actual balance results may vary.

Is that it? I thought there might be a reason they were called NPC classes rules wise.

@RowanHamilton: NPC classes are categorically weaker than their PC class "equivalent" (eg., the adept vs. a wizard). They're useful for creating (eg.) background NPCs that need to be able to aid the PCs but not overshadow them or be meaningful obstacles that basically don't risk actually stopping the PCs.
